# HTML5 Canvas Circle with three different colors

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, internet-explorer-8

I need to draw a circle using canvas in html5.

The Circle should have three different colors based on percentage.

for 0-30% it should have red
for 30-60% it should have orange
for 60-100% it should have green.

I have checked for multiple solutions. But i am unable to find a proper one.

More over this should work with IE8 as well.

I am planning to use excanvas.

Please suggest a solution for this

Comment: Could you paste the code of what you have tried so far that isn't working?

Comment: Unfortunately, canvas is not supported in IE8 http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas

Comment: Why do you need a canvas? You can use regular divs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use canvas in IE8 but I made a fallback with `div` for IE8.

It's not exactly the style that you want but it's direction.

http://jsbin.com/yoqute (Try this fiddle in IE8)

```js
$('#test').corner('50px');

if (isCanvasSupported()) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
  var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
  var radius = 70;
  
  var grd=context.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,100);
  grd.addColorStop(0,"red");
  grd.addColorStop(0.7,"orange");
  grd.addColorStop(1,"green");
  
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = grd;
  context.fill();
}

function isCanvasSupported(){
  var elem = document.createElement('canvas');
  return !!(elem.getContext && elem.getContext('2d'));
}
```

```css
#test {
  width:100px;
  height:100px; 
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#FF0000', endColorstr='#00FF00',GradientType=0 );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.corner.js"></script>

<canvas id="myCanvas">
  <div id="test"></div>
</canvas>
```

Comment: Upvote for a flexible solution. But, I am confused...I read the question as the user needs a circle that will be fully red if a javascript percentage is 0-30%, fully orange for 31-60% & fully green for 61-100%. :-//

Comment: @markE OK. I didn't see it that way, but maybe you write. Maybe, because Karthikeyan ask for canvas solution and the problem as you understand it not required canvas at all.